# Infimum of a certain set

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$ be the set $$A=\left\{ |\sin(n)| : n\in\mathbb{N} \right\},$$ then what is the infimum of $A$? I think the infimum is a positive quantity. I tried with the graph $$f(x)=|\sin(x)|,$$ but didn't come up with anything.

Comment: The word is infimum, usually abbreviated to inf. The answer is 0. Can you see why?

Comment: can you give me a compact proof of this?..@almagest

Comment: You want to show that you can find integers $m,n$ so that $n=2\pi m=\epsilon$. How do you think you might do that?

Comment: It's quite important to know if 0 is considered as a natural number here. If yes, answer is simple...

Comment: no,its not the case,you have to show that for any t>0,there is an integer n such that |sin(n)|<t according to the defination of infimum

Comment: Some people take $\mathbb{N}$ to include 0, some don't. I think we can safely assume it doesn't here. The result you need is a famous approximation result due to Dirichlet. If you have not met it before it is not that easy to prove (but entirely elementary - just use the pigeonhole principle).

Comment: Specifically, if $k$ is irrational, then there are infinitely many pairs of integers $(m,n)$ such that $|k-\frac{m}{n}|<\frac{1}{n^2}$

Comment: yes,but how does it help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that the zeroes of $\sin x$ are precisely the integer multiples of $\pi$.

By [Hurwitz' Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_(number_theory)), there are infinitely many pairs of relatively prime integers $a, b$ such that
$$\left\vert\pi - \frac{a}{b}\right\vert < \frac{1}{\sqrt{5} b^2},$$
and in particular we can approximate $\pi$ arbitrarily closely with such $(a, b)$. Multiplying through by $b$ gives that
$$|b \pi - a|< \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}b}.$$

Since the derivative of $\sin x$ is bounded in magnitude by $1$, we have for each pair $(a, b)$ that
$$|\sin a| = |\sin(b \pi - a)| \leq |b \pi - a| < \frac{1}{\sqrt{5} b}.$$

The right-hand side can be made arbitrarily small by taking large enough $b$, and so we can find (corresponding) $a$ such that $|\sin a|$ is as close to zero as desired.